# How to convert JsonObject to String for store in session in servlet?

Tags: android, json, database, servlets, authentication

How to convert JsonObject to String for store in session in servlet?

```
JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject();

jSONObject.put("user", rs.getString("user").toString());
jSONObject.put("pass", rs.getString("pass").toString());
```

Comment: you can try jsonObject.toString() to convert your json object to string

Comment: `rs.getString("user").toString()` seems redundant. `getString` already returns a String.

Comment: Can you provide some context as to what you're trying to do ?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
jSONObject.string();
```

but if this way doesn't satisfy your needs you can use the following way
to convert json object to json string  you can use this library in your build gradle

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

and in your code:

```
String string = new Gson().toJson(jSONObject );
```